# How do I implement lazy loading with a stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, lazy-loading

I have a stream of documents coming from the firestore

```
  Stream<List<GroupModel>> groupListStream() => _groupSubscriptionsStream().switchMap((subscriptions) => _firestore
      .collection(APIRoutes.groupCollection)
      .where('members.${user.id}', isEqualTo: true)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => GroupModel.fromFirestore(document).checkSubscriptions(subscriptions))
          .toList(growable: false)));

  Stream<List<GroupSubscriptionModel>> _groupSubscriptionsStream() => _firestore
      .collection(APIRoutes.userGroupSubscriptions(user.id))
      .where('isSubscribed', isEqualTo: true)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.docs.map((document) => GroupSubscriptionModel.fromFirestore(document)).toList(growable: false));
```

How could I implement lazy loading with this stream?

The examples I've seen thusfar pull a initial list with a future and put a limit in the query. Then when the listview surpasses that limit they pull again after by starting after the last document of the previous list.

But in my case I use a stream the stream groupListStream which is also dependent on another stream. So how do I implement lazy loading with my groupListStream?

Comment: Did you find a solution?